# How is sound affected when reflected off a vibrating membrane?

Tags: acoustics, reflection

When sound produced at a frequency, say 200Hz is reflected off a vibrating membrane, vibrating at another frequency, say 10Hz, what are the properties of the reflected wave in terms of frequency and amplitude? Most of the search results on Google directed to tympanic membranes or basic reflection principles, links or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part of the answer: consider the Doppler shift at each point in the membrane's vibrational cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is: model that as a problem with oscillating boundary condition. It is not so complicated numerically. Visit SE Computational Science for more details.

This would lead to the same signal but amplitude modulated. We would percieve that as a vibrato (in case of 10 Hz - generally it would be some kind of "roughness"). But anyway: the space domain in which this phenomenon is good observable (if we consider the timpani membrane surface in real room with solid reflective walls) is not huge.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question and let me know if I need to ask a new question on the forum: How is sound affected when the tension in the reflector membrane changes? The assumption here is of course that the reflector is not an infinite wall but a membrane whose tension varies.

Comment: **Simple answer: not much**. E.g. the tension in timpani membrane varies around the equilibrium tension so there is always some (and it is really not low). **Advanced answer:** That would affect the boundary impedance so the reflection ratio would vary a bit: highest at the drum rim, lowest in the middle of the membrane.